# cannot scan devices using bleakscanner

Tags: python

I run this code to detect connected devices to my pc

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
  for d in devices:
      print(d)

asyncio.run(main())
```

but get this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\scan.py", line 2, in <module>
from bleak import BleakScanner
File "D:\bleak.py", line 6, in <module>
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner
ImportError: cannot import name 'BleakClient' from partially initialized module 'bleak'       (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\bleak.py)
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the names of your scripts to something else than bleak.py to avoid the circular import error